# Implement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

i have created a list array and setting some values in that listarray on servlet . now in jsp page i need to extract these values in javascript . this code is working fine in jsp in <% ____ %> but i need to do this in javascript but i dont know how to create object of listarray in javascript and how to extract values .

variables are being used in loop are declared .

```
<%     
    List<OptimalsTutorListGetSet> alltutors = (ArrayList<OptimalsTutorListGetSet>)request.getAttribute("tutors");

    for(OptimalsTutorListGetSet t: alltutors)
    {
        name = t.getNames();
        desc = t.getDescription();
        qual =t.getQualification();
        con = t.getContact();
        email = t.getEmail();
        dis = t.getDistance();
        rating = t.getRating();
        exp = t.getExperience();
    } 
%>
```

Comment: `i need to do this in javascript but i dont know how to create object of listarray in javascript and how to extract values .` Please consider reading about Javascript before asking for help https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Comment: i am not being able to create object of this array list i now other working

Answer (score 0):

You can build the JavaScript array while looping through the Java objects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = new Array();
</script>
<%     
    List<OptimalsTutorListGetSet> alltutors = (ArrayList<OptimalsTutorListGetSet>)request.getAttribute("tutors");

    for(OptimalsTutorListGetSet t: alltutors)
    {
%>
<script type="text/javascript">

data.push({
   name: '<%=t.getNames()%>',
   desc: '<%=t.getDescription()%>',
   qual: '<%=t.getQualification()%>',
   con: '<%=t.getContact()%>',
   email: '<%=t.getEmail()%>',
   dis: '<%=t.getDistance()%>',
   rating: '<%=t.getRating()%>',
   exp: '<%=t.getExperience()%>'
});

</script>
<%
    } 
%>
```

Comment: Thank you So much dear it is working now . bundle of thanks :)